# How to know kitten's breed?

Tags: cats

Here, I had attached the picture and if anyone know the breed and how old is the kitten? He is no longer breastfeed and eat kitten food.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about identifying a pet's breed. Please see http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-discourage-pet-breed-species-identification-questions for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most cats you will find are mixes that are defined by color and length of fur then by a breed.

If your kitty were to come to a veterinary hospital he would be marked as a Domestic Short-hair (DSH), tabby or tabby-calico (looks like he has white, orange and black?).